# Why don't multiple HTML select tags show up in the DOM?

Tags: html, dom, xhtml, html-select

I'm using jQuery to dynamically populate some cascading drop-down controls when a page loads. However, only two of my three select boxes are being recognized when the page loads.

Consider the following HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head>
     <title></title> </head> <body>
     <select id="one" />
     <select id="two"  />
     <select id="three"  /> </body> </html>
```

When I open this page in IE, Firefox, or Chrome, only two of the select boxes are rendered. Only two of the three show up in the DOM (using firebug or similar), but all three show up in the source.

What can I do to have all the controls show up?

Comment: Which two of the three show up?

Comment: here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/SWJ42/

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle example. nice tool!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple: write valid HTML code. Browsers are trying their best to parse invalid HTML, but sometimes they simply choke on it.

`<select>` is not a self-closing tag, it must have a closing tag and at least one `option` or `optgroup` element.

```
<select id="one"><option></option></select>
<select id="two"><option></option></select>
<select id="three"><option></option></select>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ApgN/1)

Comment: All elements may be expressed with self-closing syntax in XHTML (unless they have required child elements, which select elements do). It just isn't HTML compatible.

Comment: @Quentin view the source of this page: http://www.webdevout.net/articles/beware-of-xhtml-examples/6.html  
It says it is valid XHTML, and it has the XHTML doctype, but it is rendered wrong.

Comment: @Greg — Yes? That demonstrates what I said. Valid but not HTML compatible.

Comment: @Quentin Whoops, I thought you were the OP trying to make a case for the self closing tags. Nevermind.

Comment: @bažmegakapa — That example isn't valid.

Comment: It was valid XHTML, but not valid HTML. Very tricky. I had expected the browsers to honor the XHTML doctype. Adding the explicit close tag worked.

Comment: While self closing tags are valid, XHTML Transitional DTD has the following definition `<!ELEMENT select (optgroup|option)+>`  This means that you MUST include at LEAST 1 optgroup OR option element inside a select element.

Comment: @SpazDude — Parse engines are switched based on Content-Type, not Doctype. By the time they hit the Doctype, it is too late (unless they were to restart parsing from scratch).

Answer (score 6):

Write [valid](http://validator.w3.org), [HTML-compatible](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#compatGuidelines) markup.

Your select elements should have explicit end tags and at least one option element.

```
<select id="one"><option>foo</option></select>
<select id="two"><option>foo</option></select>
<select id="three"><option>foo</option></select>
```